# Hold an Angular 2+ app from loading until APP_INITIALIZER finishes running?

Tags: angular

I've found how to call a service before the root component loads. But I can't find a way to keep the whole app waiting until the service successfully finishes its job. In other words, how to make it a synchronous call. The service is loading essential setting through AJAX, and I have to hold the application from starting until the call finishes.

Adding `*ngIf` to the `router-outlet` doesn't work, it causes an error.

Blocking routes with `CanActivate` will stop the views from loading, but I then have to define a loader screen and call the appropriate route from code when the promise is fulfilled. It's not very elegant.

Is there a way to tell Angular to STFU until a certain value is `true`?

Comment: Show the code that makes the call and where it currently is.

Comment: This is the function which runs during bootstrap: https://pastebin.com/NvtTKa5M

Comment: Use promises: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. eg: return from your loadsettings function by resolving the promise once your service finishes doing stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but this is AngularJS, the old one, not Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you are using the APP_INITIALIZER, but I assume you have setup a factory function for the provider. If you make sure that function returns the promise of your API call made by your service the application initialization will be blocked until the promise is resolved.

E.g. create a file called `app.initializer.ts`

```
import { FactoryProvider, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { MyDataService } from './core/my-data.service';

export function initialAppSetup(provider: MyDataService) {

 // MyDataService's getInitialData must return a promise
 return () => provider.getInitialData()
}

export const ApplicationSetupProvider: FactoryProvider = {
 provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
 useFactory: initialAppSetup,
 deps: [MyDataService],
 multi: true
}
```

In your `app.module.ts` import the ApplicationSetupProvider

```
import { ApplicationSetupProvider } from './app.initializer';
```

and add it to the providers array

```
providers: [ AuthorizationSetupProvider ],
```